# Retrieving events from web services API

Tags: api, webservices, c#, event, .net

I am trying to call the Web Services API to retrieve events using the code examples on the following pages:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_open_events_details/

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job/

However, when trying to run the sample .NET code, I receive an out of memory exception (see picture). I am receiving the correct number of records (e.g. if I try to retrieve the send events for a deployment of ten emails, I get an array of ten results), however the our of memory error occurs regardless of how many results I try to fetch.

Is this a problem with the API? Does anyone have a working example of event retrieval in .NET?

The method I am calling:

```
    public List<ClickEvent> RetrieveClickEvents(string JobID, ClientID clientID, out string status)
    {
        List<ClickEvent> cE = new List<ClickEvent>();

        SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart();
        sfp.Property = "SendID";
        sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
        sfp.Value = new string[] { JobID };

        RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
        rr.ObjectType = "ClickEvent";

        rr.Properties = new string[] { "SendID", "EventDate", "SubscriberKey" };
        rr.Filter = sfp;
        rr.ClientIDs = new ClientID[] { clientID };

        APIObject[] results;

        string requestID;
        //string status;
        status = this.proxy.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);


        //results.Length

        if (status.ToUpper() == "OK")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; )
            {
                cE.Add((ClickEvent)results[i]);
            }
        }

        return cE;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you forgotten `i++` in your for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bachovski says, the most likely cause of the out of memory error is this infinite loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; )
{
    cE.Add((ClickEvent)results[i]);
}
```

Because `i` is never incremented, the loop never terminates and the list grows until the available memory is used up.

So your code may work if you add the `i++`.